# Why "homophobia" and not "sexualism" or similar?

Tags: etymology, synonyms, sexual-minorities

A phobia is an irrational fear of something. An intolerance to something is usually an -ism, not a -phobia, as in

- sexism
- racism
- ageism

Yet people who object to homosexual practices or discriminate against homosexuals are labelled "homophobic" and their intolerance is labelled "homophobia". But homophobia should logically be an irrational fear of things that are the same (and indeed is listed with both meanings in this [list of phobias](http://phobialist.com/#H-)) and an intolerance to a particular sexuality should surely be sexualism, sexualityism, or a similar word.

So... how did the "sexualism" meaning of "homophobia" come about? Is there another word for intolerance of / discrimination against people of a particular sexuality that doesn't imply irrationality or fear?

Comment: Downvoter: care to give a reason? It's a perfectly valid, answerable question, isn't it?

Comment: I have a feeling the down-voter is someone who doesn't quite like the topic

Comment: Maybe the down-voter voted for the "homophobia should logically be" part in the question. As I am not who down-voted, I can only guess, but natural languages are quite not logical.

Comment: @kiamaluna Thanks, that makes sense - but I fear Thursagen's suggestion is probably the correct one

Comment: Aside from the historic roots of the word homophobia, "sexism" was already taken (should have been "genderism" anyway), and "sexualityism" is too hard to pronounce. I think it would be nice, though, to have a word for "aversion to homosexual behavior" that does not imply that either homosexuality, or said aversion, is a disease.

Comment: @JeffSahol - Actually, I rather like this word. It nicely points out the underlying fear behind the prejudiced behavor, and holds the perpetrators up as people to be pitied, not hated. Its a shame we can't do that with some of the other "isims" in the language.

Comment: The term is incorrectly used by people who support homosexual behavior. It's used to portray people who oppose homosexualism as biggots and thus say they have a phobia instead of saying they simply object to it. (It's similar to using alarmist instead of skeptic).

Comment: @cpburnz - You completely contradicted my point. A standard "-ism" word would say such people are bigots. A "phobia" word just says they are afraid. It doesn't even nessecarily say the fear is unjustified...

Comment: @T.E.D - Actually, if the fear was justified, then it wouldn't be a phobia. A phobia implies that they are afraid for no logical reason. Following an "-ism" does not necessarily make someone a bigot.

Comment: is homophobia really the politically correct way to say this? Is there no word for prejudice against certain sexual orientations? Homophobia does not really entail prejudice.. just fear.. EDIT: Oops, I guess I just restated the question.

Comment: @user606723 You did indeed :) The two answers so far answer the question about the origins of the word, but also make clear that "homophobia" relates to some kind of fear or psychological aversion, as opposed to simple prejudice or something based on more rational thought. It seems astonishing, but perhaps there really isn't a word that accurately portrays this.

Comment: What do we call people who discriminate against the ugly and the poor? Answer - nothing. We don't have a word for that. I wonder why not?

Comment: I'm glad you posted this. I asked myself the same question. They now use the terms "biphobia" and "transphobia", also terrific misnomers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=homophobia&searchmode=none)

> homophobic
>
> ```
> by 1971, from homo- (2) + -phobia. Related: Homophobe; homophobia
> ```
>
> (which is said to date from 1969)

it points to the **second meaning of homo**, which is the slang version

> comb. form meaning "homosexual," abstracted since early 20c. from
>   homosexual

This can be read as a "phobia (fear) of homosexuals"

As [@Mr Shiny's answer says](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41973/why-homophobia-and-not-sexualism-or-similar/41981#41981), George Weinberg introduced this word "to refer to heterosexual men's fear that others might think they are gay"

Later Kenneth Smith was the first person to use homophobia as a personality profile to describe the psychological aversion to homosexuality.

Answer (score 14):

[Wikipedia states](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Homophobia#Etymology) that this word was originally coined to refer to a straight man's fear that others might think he was gay. Its scope expanded to include all anti-homosexual prejudices within a few years when activists started using it. George Weinberg, a psychologist, considered these prejudices to be a literal fear and not simply prejudice. (Perhaps another way of looking at this is why isn't racism racephobia?)

Comment: +1 - But I'd stipulate there's more fear involved in anti-homosexual people than just that. There's also the fear in the non-inlined that contact with gay folks will somehow "infect" them with it. In the gay-inclined (closeted gays), there's the fear that they will lose their resolve and "become" gay. Its no accident that many of the most rabid "homophobes" turn out to be closeted gay people themselves. There is a very real fear there.

Comment: @T.E.D. or a fear that you are yourself gay and so you blame all the others for 'tempting' you. The same way that the medieval church blamed women for men's lust.

Comment: @T.E.D.: you're right, and that fear is mentioned as well in the Wikipedia article. I just wanted to point out that the original coining of this word did focus on actual fear.

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and New 安宇: *Racism* is roughly equivalent to *xenophobia*.  Noting that only causes more confusion-- *xenophobia* is fear of that which is different and *homophobia* indicates fear of the same.  Taking it a step further, *sexism* should probably be called *genderism*, and discrimination based on certain sexual preferences might logically be called *fetishism*, but the current definition of *fetishism* doesn't relate to discrimination at all.

Comment: The suffix phobia in homophobia does not necessarily means phobia or fear (in common language). Etymology isn't everything.

Comment: @Albertus: In this case the etymology of the word is clearly indicating that the _phobia_ was originally intended to mean "fear". The etymology of the word isn't its current meaning, but it does explain the somewhat counter-intuitive nature of the word.

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and New 安宇: I actually think your answer is right when you say that "its scope expanded to include all anti-homosexual prejudices", but I believe it would be even more neutral and exact to say that if you discriminate, object to or simply dislike homosexuality (for whatever reason, rational or not) you are labelled homophobic. Not my case at all, by the way.

Comment: @Albertus: The point of this answer was not to document everything about the current use of the word, but rather to explain why the word has _-phobia_ in it.